# Rank of image intensity matrix

Tags: computer-vision, rank

I've been reading a paper about using [Matrix Completion for Photometric Stereo](http://perception.csl.illinois.edu/matrix-rank/Files/robust_v19.pdf) but I am having some troubles in **section 2.2** trying to understand why irrespective of the number of pixels and the number of images $$rank(\mathbf{O}) = 3$$
where $\mathbf{O}$ is the matrix with the images linearized and stacked as column vectors.

Can someone give me a hint to understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images described in the paper are not independent, but are uniquely defined by a lighting direction which is 3 dimensional.

You could thus construct any conceivable image (in this model) by lighting the scene from 3 orthogonal directions (x, y and z for instance). This corresponds to the rank being 3.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there some other way you could explain it. I kinda understand what you are saying and based on what I've read intuitively makes sense but it will be haunting me until I really understand it.

Comment: By "lighting the scene from 3 orthogonal directions" you don't mean 3 images with different incoming light-directions, do you?

Comment: The other way, maybe not correct, I was thinking of it was that, any pixel has a uniquely surface-normal vector which is of dimension 3, therefore independently of the number of pixels or images we will have a unique normal, but still I am not 100% convinced of it.

Comment: That's actually equivalent to what I'm saying. From 3 images with orthogonal lighting directions we could recover the surface normal in each pixel of the image. So yes, it is because the normal has dimension 3.

Comment: Could you give an example, maybe more math-based, in which something similar to the case I'm dealing with happens? Like I said, intuitively I see why the rank-3 but I would like a more convincing statement.

Comment: Ok, the rank of a matrix is the largest collection of linearly independent column vectors in the matrix. In this case, each column vector is an image. As we can construct any image via a linear combination of 3 images with orthogonal lighting direction, the largest number of linearly independent column vectors we can have is 3.